# Configuring VirtualHost in Spring Boot application embedded Tomcat server in Windows

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, dns, windows-server

I have a private Windows server running a Spring Boot jar file and I can access it via the IP address. I have a few websites available which I am able to access via the IP address and filters. (Note that this is running on port 54654 as I have other WEB APIs as well). I have a new domain registered online and I would like to access the server by the domain name which would redirect to my server address.

But the issue is, the browser shows the IP address instead of the domain name. I tried forward with masking but it is not working as I expected (it puts the site inside an iFrame and I cannot access browser properties etc). I want to access my site like `www.abc.com` and it should not change to `<host-ip-address>:<port>`. I understand the issue is from server side and do not know how to make it remain in the domain name. I tried a new entry with hosts.txt file but it does not seem to work.

I have searched for solution online for hours and could not find a specific solution for Spring Boot and changing VirtualHost settings in tomcat is not clear to me in this case. Is there any settings for this in application.properties file?

Comment: Would you be able to provide us with your dns records as well?

Comment: is that from my domain name supplier or my host machine?

Comment: From your domain supplier.

Comment: Are you accessing the URL from inside the same network or on the same machine? Can you route your request through a VPN or a cellular connection so you can see how it looks from the world's perspective?

Comment: Remove the `Parked` entry, otherwise your website will be served by your DNS registry. They probably server a page, which redirects to your IP after a few seconds. Remark also, that you'll need to use `http://catleaplabs.com:55555` to access your website.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz unless I host it in port 80 (default) I cannot change the :55555 from appearing in the URL? (it looks abnormal to see port number in website). I tried to portproxy it but it does not seem to work. 
`>netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=55555 connectaddress=127.0.0.1`

Comment: ok now I have my web service running in port 8080 (default) but still it gets redirected to port 55555. I removed the portproxy and nginx configs. Is this some issue with my domain provider?

Comment: After you make changes to DNS, you need to wait for DNS caches to expire (your entries are cacheable for up to 10 minutes) and probably restart your browser. As for the port: you can simply run Tomcat on port 80.

Comment: Your DNS provider removed your `A` entry and added its own `34.102.136.180` again.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz you are right. I checked the headers... https://imgur.com/a/nfBWADl

Comment: Now again the A record is shown as Parked. What is going on. I am contacting support now...

Comment: OK I got an idea now. I used forwarding (with and without masking) to check out the issue and seems like if I remove the forwarding info AFTER the A record is changed, it gets parked automatically. Not sure why this happened, but I checked the site in incognito and it works. Now addressing the original question. Can I access the site with my server running in port 55555?

Comment: Alright. I fixed the port forwarding using nginx. Issue resolved. Thank you @PiotrP.Karwasz BillHorvath JuliusKreutz for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is the summary of things I learnt from this requirement. Thank you @PiotrP.Karwasz for your extended support.

1. You can run your server in any port but the domain name provider can only point to the default port (80)
2. If you change your forwarding setting AFTER you have edited your A record, your domain will be moved to Parked state (Parked is when your domain is shown as "taken" to others who visit it and it will not point to your A record's IP address). In such case, you have to modify your A record again.
3. You can use nginx to configure reroute from http port (80) to any port your server runs in. My nginx configuration:

   ```
   server {
   listen 80;
   server_name <my-site>.com;

       location / {
       proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
       proxy_pass         "http://127.0.0.1:<my-port>";
       }
   }
   ```
4. Domain name changes will take time to reflect in DNS (24-48 hours) and you can check it by clearing cache or by incognito window (private browsing).

Comment: @Piotr P. Karwasz how do I credit you with the bounty?

Comment: no credit is due. BTW: the concept _"forwarding setting"_ is specific to your DNS provider (your should give its name in the question). Most name registrars don't mess with your DNS records.